# How can I use # in a C preprocessor macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to use a preprocessor directive in a macro? Can/how can this accomplished?

```
#define     HTTP_REQUEST_RETURN_ERROR(error)    *errCode = error;
                                                 #ifdef DEBUG
                                                        LeaveCriticalSection(&debugOutputLock);
                                                 #endif
                                                 return NULL
```

Thanks in advance,
Jori.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also, of course, define the macro twice, with different definitions:

```
#if defined DEBUG
#define HTTP_REQUEST_RETURN_ERROR(error) do { *errCode = error;\
                                          LeaveCriticalSection(&debugOutputLock);\
                                          return NULL;\
                                         } while(0)
#else
#define HTTP_REQUEST_RETURN_ERROR(error) do { *errCode = error;\
                                           return NULL;\
                                         } while(0)
#endif
```

That makes sure to avoid the (trivially optimizable) run-time `if` that [xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12106784/28169) used. It also wraps the macro bodies in the typical `do ... while`, to make it look like a statement.

**UPDATE**: To clarify, multi-statement macros in C are often wrapped (in the macro definition) in a `do ... while(0)` loop, since that makes the entire text into a single statement. This lets the usage of the macro work well with scopes and semicolons.

For instance, consider this:

```
if(httpRequestFailed())
  HTTP_REQUEST_RETURN_ERROR(404);
else
  processResults();
```

Without the `do ... while(0)`, the above would be a syntax error since there would be multiple statements between the `if` and the `else`. Just adding braces to the macro expansion isn't very clean, since the desirable statement-like usage like the above would result in expansion of

```
if(httpRequestFailed())
  { ... /* code omitted */ };
```

which is not very clean, braces following a code scope are not typically followed by a semicolon.

Comment: Why do you have to wrap it in do-while statement?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot nest preprocessor directives in a `#define`.

Comment: It's a shame. I actually once tried making one to create a new macro, but give a compiler error if my macro name was already in use. Too bad it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Define `DEBUG` and then use the normal if statement.

```
#define DEBUG 0

#define HTTP_REQUEST_RETURN_ERROR(error)  *errCode = error;
                                          if (DEBUG) LeaveCriticalSection(&debugOutputLock);
                                          return NULL
```